# Выбор режима браузера в IE10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

По неизвестной причине при загрузке страницы браузер выбирает просмотр в режиме совместимости. Конечно, можно в ручную выбрать режим браузера, но это неудобно. Может быть, кто-нибудь знает, как заставить запускать страницу сразу в режиме IE10?

Comment: поговаривают, что ie отправляет статистику, когда пользователи переключаются в режим совместимости. А умные дядьки в МС сидят, смотрят и добавляют в специальный список, который браузер регулярно и подтягивает.

Comment: [Забавная статья][1] про IE и его режимы с хабра.


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/201172/

Comment: Человек много рейджит хотя ИЕ особо и не виноват. Смотрите сюда http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699485(v=vs.85).aspx. Также проверьте стоит ли правильный doctype.

Сам список - https://iecvlist.microsoft.com/IE11/1375395130872/iecompatviewlist.xml

Comment: Решил добавлением <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />, который всегда использует последний доступный режим отображения независимо от doctype.